# ElectronJS does not connect to serial port

Tags: angular, electron, serial-port

The application is an Angular application, in Chrome/Edge/Mogilla the browser asks me to connect to the device.
Here is my code:

```js
connect() {

    if (!this.port) {
      this.serial.connect((port: any) => {
        this.port = port;
      });
    }
}
```

And this is what it shows in connect() with Chrome:
[image]

Electron throws:
`main.b0202a271531c6f7.js:1 Requesting port error: NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'requestPort' on 'Serial': No port selected by the user.`

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nano-lk8wen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please share more code, if possible a stackblitz with the minimal code to reproduce the issue!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nano-lk8wen?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Here is a stackblitz, the connection button is the button I need

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming internally in the `ngx-serial` project, I was able to replicate the issue when I clicked on connect and then did not select any port and gave cancel, this should be raised a bug in the github repository, on checking the error, it looks like a non blocking error, meaning, you can still work even if you get this error.

There is not much that can be done for this error, except raise an issue on github, to handle the scenario where the user does not select any port!

```
public async connect(callback:Function) {
      this.keepReading = true;
      if ("serial" in navigator) {
        // The Web Serial API is supported by the browser.
        let nav: any = navigator;
        const ports = await nav.serial.getPorts();
  
        try {
          this.port = await nav.serial.requestPort();
  
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Requesting port error: " + error); // <-------------------- problem here!
          return;
        }
  
        try {
         await this.port.open(this.options);
  
  
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Opening port error: " + error);
          return;
        }
  
        const textEncoder = new TextEncoderStream();
        this.writableStreamClosed = textEncoder.readable.pipeTo(this.port.writable);
        this.writer = textEncoder.writable.getWriter();
  
        this.readLoop();
  
        callback(this.port);
  
      } else {
        console.error("This browser does NOT support the Web Serial API");
      }
  
    }
  }
```

Comment: My issue is that Electron does not ask me to select a serial port as the browsers.